# Checking for equality to the same value for more than one variable C#

Tags: c#

Is there a shorthand version of this comparison statement:

```
if (txtId.Text != string.Empty && txtName.Text != string.Empty && txtBOD.Text != string.Empty && txtPhone.Text != string.Empty)
{//do something }
```

Is there something like: if all these textboxs values != string.Empty, then do something

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put the textboxes in an array and use linq like that:

```
TextBox[] boxes = new [] {txtId, txtName, txtBOD, txtPhone};
if (boxes.All(b => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Text)))
    // do something
```

You should store the array in a member variable of your window so you don't have to create it again for every check.

---

Or (as Habib pointed out) if all those textboxes are in one container control *and they are the only textboxes on that control* you could use this:

```
if (containingControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(b => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Text)))
    // do something
```

`OfType<>()` returns a enumeration of all controls in the `containingControl`'s control collection that are of type `TextBox` and you can then simply iterate through this sequence with `All`.

---

Note (as others pointed out) that it's a better practice to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` than comparing against `string.Empty` (since a null check is already included, though that should not matter at a textbox).

Comment: +1, and if the OP has control in a single panel/control then the same could be done like: `panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(b=> b.Text != string.Empty);` *(for winform, similar approach could be adopted for others)*

Comment: would suggest testing for `b.Length!=0` or `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)`

Comment: @BastianThiede I agree, just copied the code from OP and didn't think about that point.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method like this:

```
private bool AreAllEmpty(params TextBox[] toCheck)
{
    foreach (var tb in toCheck)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or this way with LINQ:

```
private bool AreAllEmpty(params TextBox[] toCheck)
{
    return toCheck.All(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text));
}
```

And then just pass it your collection of text boxes, e.g. like this:

```
if(AreAllEmpty(textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4))
{
    // do something../
}
```

This approach is good if you're like me and like to reduce method size by off-loading separate operations into their own methods.  (This has many advantages: DRY, separation of concerns, etc.)

Comment: Nice idea I'd add an example how to use (and maybe use linq instead of foreach, but that could be a matter of taste).